# NSTableView single click action

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

How to capture the event of single-clicking on a row of an `NSTableView` and trigger an action? (Idealy, it should trigger the action for left clicks only, not right clicks, but this is not required.)

Implementing `-tableViewSelectionDidChange` of the table view's delegate is close to what I want. However, if a row is currently selected, clicking on that row again doesn't call `-tableViewSelectionDidChange` since the selection didn't change.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Connect the selector action event on the table view (better from interface designed), then

```
- (IBAction)onAction:(id)sender {
    NSTableView* tableView = (NSTableView*)sender;
    // use tableView.selectedColumn/tableView.selectedRow to get the selection
}
```

You can also connect it from code if you want fro viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView setAction:@selector(onAction:)];
```

Comment: Awesome. That's something not obvious and not well documented